# Get data by angularjs $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

I have the following angularJS function that get data by $resource ,it works and push this data to vm.data array, ,but when I try to get vm.data in controller i get null ,This last line of the following code print null value

```
   function loadAll() {
    Questiongroup.query({}).$promise.then(function(group){
        console.log(group);
        for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
           var grouptitle=group[i].title
            Question.questionsByQuestionGroup({id:group[i].id}).$promise.then(function(question){
                vm.question = question; 
               for(var j=0;j<question.length;j++){
                   vm.data.push({ group: grouptitle, question: question[j].question , questiontype: question[j].type });

                   console.log(vm.data)      //this line print correct data 
                   }
         });
        }
      });
    }

    loadAll();
    console.log(vm.data);         //This line print null
```

Comment: This is not how async call work as you are expecting, you can get it result when response is received, here you will get data inside `.then` function of `$resource`

Comment: please give me more details how can i implement that?

Comment: have you read a [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) ?

Comment: You need to define $scope.vm outside the fucntion and than write all results in this scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that last `console.log` prints `null`  is that it executes **before** the functions given to the `.then` methods. The functions given as arguements to `.then` methods are invoked by the `$q` service **after** the data returns from the server.

The `loadAll` function should **return** a derived promise which can be used to retrieve the `vm.data` **after** being assembled. This involves **chaining** promises and using the `$q.all` method.

```
function loadAll() {
    var topPromise = Questiongroup.query({}).$promise;

    var derivedPromise = topPromise.then(function(group){
        var promiseList = [];
        console.log(group);
        for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
            var itemPromise  = getItemPromise(group[i]);
            promiseList.push(itemPromise);                        
        };
        //return $q.all promise for chaining
        return $q.all(promiseList);
    });

    //return promise
    return derivedPromise;
};
```

Then use the returned promise.

```
var loadAllPromise = loadAll();

loadAllPromise.then(function (vmData) {
    console.log(vmData);
});
```

The above example shows how to create a promise that returns an array of data from an array of promises. It is intuitively obvious to extend that to multiple levels of iteration.

---

### **AngularJS** `$q.all` also works with hashes.

```
function loadAll() {
    var topPromise = Questiongroup.query({}).$promise;

    var derivedPromise = topPromise.then(function(group){
        var promiseHash = {};
        console.log(group);
        for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
            var itemPromise  = getItemPromise(group[i]);
            promiseHash[group[i].id] = itemPromise;                        
        };
        //return $q.all promise for chaining
        return $q.all(promiseHash);
    });

    //return promise
    return derivedPromise;
};
```

The above example returns a promise that contains a hash (associative array) of data.

```
loadAllPromise.then(function (dataHash) {
    console.log(dataHash);
});
```

From the Docs:

> ### all(promises);
>
> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> An array or hash of promises.
>
> **Returns**
>
> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

--[AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)